# Failing Microphone in iPhone 7

Tags: iphone

No app requiring microphone works on my iPhone 7, including calls. Strange thing is that calls fail with call fail message, not just have bad connections or other end complaining about not being able to hear. Other apps also refuse to work. For example ‘Voice notes’ state ‘no audio devices found’.

Comment: Most likely explanation is that the microphone has gone faulty. You'll need to get it inspected by an Apple authorized service provider.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Phone diagnostics (https://apps.apple.com/us/app/phone-diagnostics/id1171677218) to check all microphones on your iPhone.[image]